# Swipe pattern on a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, swipe

I'm developing an app of a culture event of my country. I'm developing for iOS an Android. I'm an Android user and for me is common the swipe-to-left pattern to change screens. I would like to know if most users of both operating systems can deduce that they have to swipe-to-left to change screens. Do you think I have to add other elements to help the user to deduce it?  I'll attach the picture of home screen of both OS.

**1. Android version**

[image]

**2. iOS version**

[image]

Comment: Is this a list of items? The cutoff at the bottom suggests a swipe-to-top action to scroll down, not a swipe-to-left to scroll right.

Comment: @phyrfox - It appears the stories stack top-to-bottom and can be scrolled through with a swipe-to-top action. An individual story can be visited by a swipe-to-left action.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey you are right. "La Feria" is the home of the app: the main components of the culture event (description, the next event and a contest). "Programación" is "Calendar" and its the next section of the app. I have 7 different sections in the app. If that isn't intuitive, what could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, your UI is good to go. Also yes, user will get idea of swipe to left to see other categories in your app.

Also I would like to give u suggestion for some marked place in below screenShot as follow:-

1. Change black colour rather use light shady colour as I seeing your screenshot it seems that your festival(culture event) is a colourful and bright.
2. The selected category title should be bigger and bold than rest one like in your case La Feria is selected one and other one is Programacion(sorry for spelling)
3. which is not selected, make it's alpha value(look like shadow) less kinda shady and make a bit more gap between the two title. This way user will see that Programacion title and seeing it shady will bring out keen interest of looking at what is at that category.

Hope I conveyed myself very well. If anything else do let me know.

[image]

Comment: I think your suggestions are very relevant to improve the user experience. Thank you.

Comment: @CamiloSacanamboy your welcome ! :)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with providing simple buttons at the bottom? It will be more helpful to directly tap and the button and move to the next category/screens.

[image]

Adding any button at the top makes it difficult for a user to reach the top via single hand. I am assuming that the user is going to use this application via a single hand, since in your old case he/she can just swipe the screen to the left using the thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Since the topics are meant to be side by side and the content in a topic continues below, there should be indication of these two features.

The cut-off does indicate there is more below, however, if a an item happens to end near the bottom of the screen, the cut-off won't be oblivious. Therefore, for the swipe up/down to be obvious you need some sort of continued below indication.

The swipe left/right to swap topics will be more clear if you add arrows to the topic bar "La Feria", "Progam", ...) e.g...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXiuni.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>